# How to set up WPLANG in wp-config.php for 4 languages?

Tags: multi-language

Good day!
I don't know much code so I've been researching on how to modify my wp-config.php file so that the content and widgets of my site will show in the four languages (aside from English) I have on there. I don't care about translating the WP interface, just the content. The WP .mo files in the languages in question are already in the wp-content/languages folder.
How would I define 4 languages in wp-config.php? Like this?

define ('WPLANG', 'es_ES'); ('WPLANG', 'de_DE'); ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR'); ('WPLANG', 'ca_CA')

I've been trying things out (only way for me to learn) but ended up destroying the file and having to restore it. Besides, like I said, no reliable info on the net.
Cheers :)

Comment: That won't work, there's no functionality in WordPress that allows you to edit a post in more than one language anyway. To do this find a multilingual plugin to install, like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-language/)

Comment: as @One-Trick-Pony says, defining it like you want in the `wp-config.php` is impossible. I would like to suggest another multilingual plugin though: WPML (http://wpml.org)

Comment: perhaps this may be of use for anybody doesn't want plugins:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/multilingual-wordpress-site-multisite/

Answer (score 4):

I just found this which I applied and works perfectly:

If you have your blogs installed in subdirectories you could use this solution:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/enblog') === 0) {
    define ('WPLANG', 'en_US');
} else {
    define ('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');
}
```

... and so on. Good luck!

Comment: This is an old question/answer but wouldn't this cause the language to change for everyone browsing the website when multiple people are present at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

if you are somehow using .mo files to translate the content strings (and your theme is calling the necessary __() or _e() functions)
then you could possibly get away with a much simpler option than wpml.

You could use the simple but effective plugin http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/other-plugins/in-their-language/

it detects language of browser if possible and then sets the wp locale accordingly.